# a faster way of running sapply in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, sapply

I'm trying to find a faster way to run a function, which is looking for the median value for every given day in a time period.  Is there a faster way than running Sapply in a for loop?

```
for(z in unique(as.factor(df$group))){
all[[z]]<- sapply(period, function(x) median(df[x == df$date & df$group==z, 'y']))
}
```

Sample data:

```
date<-as.Date("2011-11-01") + 
runif( 1000, 
       max=as.integer( 
           as.Date( "2012-12-31") - 
               as.Date( "2011-11-01")))
period<-as.Date(min(df$date):max(df$date), origin = "1970-01-01")
df <- data.frame(date=date, y = rnorm(1000), group=factor(rep(letters[1:4], each=250)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using base R function [`tapply`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/tapply)

```
tapply(df$y, df$date, median)
```

**Update**. Judging by your comment above, you need one column for each group? That's also a one-liner:

```
tapply(df$y, list(df$date, df$group), median)
```

Comment: Here is the potential source of your confusion. First, let's make my example reproducible - insert ``set.seed(1)`` at the beginning of OP's code. Then, please compare ``length(unique(df$date))`` (gives 1000) with ``length(unique(format(df$date, "%Y/%m/%d")))`` (gives 391). Do you see why? For some reason, unique doesn't work well with Date types.

Comment: Yes. It's actually quite confusing that Date object may store two different dates that have identical print representation, but are not identical: after ``x <- as.Date(c(1.1, 1.0), origin = "1970-01-01")``, ``x[1] == x[2]`` returns ``FALSE``.

Comment: BTW, the reason why ``tapply`` worked correctly is because it converts its second argument to factor, which truncates decimal parts of dates.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand right, you want to `split by group` and then calculate the `median` within each `date`. Here's a `data.table` solution.

**Edit:** The problem was with the `date` format of your dataset. It seems to report the number of unique elements wrong. So, I had to recast it to `POSIXct` format.

```
df$date <- as.POSIXct(as.character(df$date), format="%Y-%m-%d")
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)

setkey(dt, "date")
dt.out <- dt[, lapply(letters[1:4], 
          function(x) median(y[group == x])), by = date]
```

This is identical to Victor's output.

Comment: I need columns for every factor in the group (four columns + a date column), not one column for all the groups.

Comment: this also gives me multiple values for some days